# proof: For all real numbers x and y, |x| · |y| = |x y|.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Here is my attempt at proving this inequality. Keep in mind that this my first time dealing with absolute values with inequality in a proof.

proof:

> Suppose $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. By definition of absolute value, $x≥0$ or $x<0$ and $y≥0$ or $y<0$.
> **Case 1 $(x≥0;y≥0)$:**
> In this case, By definition of absolute value, $|xy|=xy$. Then, $xy=x*y=|x|*|y|$. Thus, $|xy|=|x|*|y|$.
> **Case 2 $(x≥0;y<0)$:**
> In this case, By definition of absolute value, $|xy|= -(xy)=(x)*(-y)$. Then, $x=|x|$ and $-y=|-y|=|y|$.
> Thus, |xy|=|x|*|y|.
> **Case 3 $(x<0;y≥0)$:**
> In this case, $|xy|=-(xy)=(-x)*(y)$. By definition of absolute value, $-x=|-x|=|x|$ and $y=|y|$. 
> Thus, $|xy|=(-x)*(y) =|x|*|y|$.
> **Case 4 $(x<0;y<0)$:**
> In this case, $|xy|=-(xy)=(-x)*(-y)$. By definition of absolute value, $-x=|-x|=|x|$ and  $-y=|-y|=|x|$.
> Thus, $|xy|=|x|*|y|$.
> Hence in all cases $|xy| = |x|*|y|$.

Is this proof acceptable? I would appreciate some tips on how to improve this proof.

Comment: It's not an inequality.

Comment: Case $4$ is wrong. If $x<0$ and $y<0$ then $xy>0.$ Also, $(-x)(-y)\neq -(xy).$

Comment: The first item "by definition of absolutely value..." is not correct. What you can say is that by the trichotomy axiom, $x$ is exactly one of  negative, positive, or zero. The definition of absolute value has no influence on properties of arbitrary real numbers.

Comment: You could probably safely say "every number is either negative or nonnegative, and we work on cases using this; in the first case, both $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative, and so $|x| = x$(by the definition of abs. val) and $|y| = y$ similarly."

Comment: Your PROOF may use those, but the thing you're tying to prove, namely $|x| \cdot |y| = |xy|$, uses only equality, so it's an equation,  not an inequality.

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews 1- I thought that since it uses the symbols (>,<, ≥), it is an inequality. 2- can you explain case 4 in more detail because I don't understand. shouldn't the product of two negative be negative? or since they are real numbers and not integers?.

Comment: @ John Hughes thanks for the help.

Comment: @– Thomas Andrews  oops! after substituting x and y with actual numbers, i understand why (−x)(−y)≠−(xy). sorry for being dumb. :P